# Update database with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, pdo

Because of the layout I can't use another `<form>` tag so I am trying to use javascript to update the database.

Since the code is just changing the URL with `window.location.href` it's not reloading the page to run the `if` statement.

Here is my code:

```
$check_view = $member->getUsersView($user_id);
if((isset($_GET['view-all'])) && $check_view != $_GET['view-all'])
{
    $view_all = $_GET['view-all'];
    $database->query('UPDATE users SET view_all = :viewall WHERE id = :userid', array(':viewall' => $view_all, ':userid' => $user_id));
}

<div onclick="javascript:window.location.href = \'page.php?action=list&'.(isset($_GET['view-all']) && $_GET['view-all']=="No" && $check_view=="No" ? 'view-all=Yes' : 'view-all=No').'\';">'.(isset($_GET['view-all']) && $_GET['view-all']=="No" && $check_view=="No" ? 'Show All' : 'Hide').'</div>
```

Anyone able to give me a hand with this?

**EDIT:** Thanks to the help of Matt I was able to get it working:

```
if(isset($_GET['view-all']))
{
    $check_view = $member->getUsersView($user_id);

    if($check_view != $_GET['view-all'])
    {
        $view_all = $_GET['view-all'];

        $database->query('UPDATE users SET view_all = :viewall WHERE id = :userid', array(':viewall' => $view_all, ':userid' => $user_id));
    }
}

$users_view = $member->getUsersView($user_id);

$view_all = "No";
$hide_show = "Hide";
if((isset($_GET['view-all']) && ($_GET['view-all']=="No")) || ($users_view=="No"))
{
    $view_all = "Yes";
    $hide_show = "Show All";
}

$data = '<a href="page.php?action=list&view-all='.$view_all.'">'.$hide_show.'</a>';
```

Comment: Why use a `<div>` + onclick instead of just a regular `<a>`?

Comment: You need to show the client-side output for your DIV, not your server-side PHP code.

Comment: For the love of **GOD** please define your `onclick` function in a `<script>` block and then call the function from there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="page.php?action=list&view-all=<?=(isset($_GET['view-all']) && $_GET['view-all']=="No" && $check_view=="No" ? "Yes" : "No"?>">
<?=isset($_GET['view-all']) && $_GET['view-all']=="No" && $check_view=="No" ? 'Show All' : 'Hide'?>
</a>
```

The above code will work but is ***UGLY AS SIN***. Try cleaning it up:

```
<?php
$view_all = "No";
$hide_show = "Hide";
if (isset($_GET['view-all']) && $_GET['view-all']=="No" && $check_view=="No") {
    $view_all = "Yes";
    $hide_show = "Show All";
}
?>

<a href="page.php?action=list&view-all=<?= $view_all ?>"><?= $hide_show ?></a>
```

Comment: Any idea why "Show All" displays again after I click it? I have to click it a second time to get "Hide" to display. The "Hide" works fine, if I click it "Show All" displays.

Comment: @Draven not really, I just reorganized your code so it would be cleaner; I didn't check it for logical accuracy (sorry).

Comment: No problem. I just realized why. I am defining `$check_view` before it's updating the database with the new value.